# Node.js script stops unfinished without a sound

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a script for parsing some bitcoin blockchains.

I'm using async queue function from this [great lib](https://github.com/caolan/async) but code seems to stop without any message in the middle of processing, what can cause this?

queue.drain never calls because the execution is just vanishing!
Is there a way to get a reason of script-crashing? I tried using node debugger but had no success.

```
'use strict';
var request = require ('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

var blocksTotal = 0, k = 0;
var data = [];

var queue = async.queue((task, callback) => {
    request('https://blockchain.info/rawblock/' + task.hash, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            let parsedBlock = JSON.parse(response.body);
            //console.log('processing block [' + i + '/' + blocks.length + ']...');
            parseTransactions(parsedBlock.tx);
            callback(err);
        };
    });
}, 100);

queue.drain = () => {
    console.log('all blocks processed. done.')
}

var convertTime = function(UNIX_timestamp){
  let a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
  let year = a.getFullYear();
  let month = +a.getMonth()+1 >= 10 ? +a.getMonth+1 : '0' + (+a.getMonth()+1);
  let date = a.getDate() >= 10 ? a.getDate() : '0'+a.getDate();
  let hour = a.getHours() >= 10 ? a.getHours() : '0'+a.getHours();
  let min = a.getMinutes() >= 10 ? a.getMinutes() : '0'+a.getMinutes();
  let sec = a.getSeconds() >= 10 ? a.getSeconds() : '0'+a.getSeconds();
  let time = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec + ' ' + date + '/' + month + '/' + year ;
  return time;
}



console.log('requesting blocks...');
//make a req to blockchain to get a neat JSON
request('https://blockchain.info/blocks/?format=json', (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        let today = JSON.parse(response.body);//get today's blocks in JSON
        console.log('got blocks, parsing blocks...');
        parseBlocks(today.blocks);
    };
});
//parse blocks and get transactions from it
var parseBlocks = function(blocks) {
    console.log('got ' + blocks.length + ' blocks...')
    blocksTotal = blocks.length;
    var i = 0;
    blocks.forEach((block) => {
        queue.push({hash: block.hash}, (err) => {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            i++;
            //console.log('finished block ' + i + '\r');
            process.stdout.write(queue.running() + ' in queue\r')
            });
        //request('https://blockchain.info/rawblock/' + block.hash, (err, response, body) => {
            //if (err) console.error(err);
            //if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                //let parsedBlock = JSON.parse(response.body);
                //i++;
                //console.log('processing block [' + i + '/' + blocks.length + ']...');
                //parseTransactions(parsedBlock.tx, i);
            //};
        //});
    });
};
//get UNIX timestamp and transaction value and write it to file
var parseTransactions = function(transactions){
    console.log('got ' + transactions.length + ' transactions from block. processing...')
    transactions.forEach((transaction) => {
        let value = 0;
        transaction.inputs.forEach((input) =>{
            if (input.prev_out) {
                value += input.prev_out.value;
            };
        });
        if (value !== 0) {
                value = value.toString();
                if (value.length > 8) {
                    value = value.slice(-0,-8) + '.' + value.substr(-8)
                }else{
                    while(value.length !== 8){
                        value = '0' + value;
                    }
                    value = '0.' + value;
                };
            //let info = (convertTime(transaction.time) + ';' + value + '\n');
            //fs.appendFile('data', info, () => {
                //console.log('Data saved to file');
            //});
            let info = [transaction.time, value];
            data.push(info);
        };
    });
}
```

[code at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0CEhWW5y)

Comment: Questions about code must include that code directly pasted into your question and formatted properly, not only available via an external link.  That is the policy here on stack overflow.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry, i just don't like the editor, it often breaks all identation.

Comment: You can always paste the code in here: http://jsbeautifier.org/, hit the beautify button, indent everything one extra block and then paste it in and you're good.  Yes, the editor here is from the dark ages for people who write code.  For how much code is posted here, I'm surprised nothing is ever done about that, but when I've asked about it on Meta, I've been met with no understanding.

Comment: I wonder if you could be throwing an exception somewhere such as from `JSON.parse(response.body);` or `parseTransactions(parsedBlock.tx)` which would cause you to miss the calling of `callback(err)` which would make things stall.  Your error handling is also flawed so any error or statusCode that's not 200 will cause you so skip calling of `callback(err)` and things will stall.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank a lot! the problem was just obvious bad statuscode in response stalling the code without reach to `callback(err)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it seems to have led to the solution:

To make sure your code never stalls, you have to make sure you are always calling `callback(err)`.  If any code path might not call that, then the async library will get stalled as it's still waiting for that last async operation to signal its completion.

As such, you have several ways that it would get stalled:

1. If your `request()` operation actually reports an error.
2. If your `request()` operation actually returns a status code other than 200.
3. If you throw an exception anywhere inside your request callback handler such as in `JSON.parse()` or `parseTransactions()`.

Here's a more robust implementation:

```
var queue = async.queue((task, callback) => {
    request('https://blockchain.info/rawblock/' + task.hash, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            callback(err);
        }
        else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            try {
                let parsedBlock = JSON.parse(response.body);
                //console.log('processing block [' + i + '/' + blocks.length + ']...');
                parseTransactions(parsedBlock.tx);
                callback(err);
             } catch(e) {
                callback(e);
             }
        } else {
             callback(new Error("statuscode was: " + response.statusCode));
        }

    });
}, 100);
```

FYI, a huge advantage to using the now-standard ES6 promise structure instead of the async library with manual callbacks is that it makes this kind of stuff a lot simpler and more foolproof.  It automatically propagates errors.  It automatically catches async exceptions and turns them into errors.  It makes it much easier to robust write error handling code.

Comment: in addition want to say what error was caused by wrong 409 statuscode, which means i made too many requests to api in a time. Thats because i did this in 100 threads ( as a second argument to async.queue). Lowering threads to 10 solved the entire problem with statuscodes, but now i also process errors with more care.